# Add total column that repeats its value based on the number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
item_id  sales
   1      10
   2      30
   3      70
```

I want to return the table with an additional column that is the sum of the sales.
So output should look like

```
item_id  sales  total
   1      10     110
   2      30     110
   3      70     110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `SUM()` as a window function:

```sql
SELECT item_id, sales, SUM(sales) OVER () AS total
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY item_id;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can instead use a subquery to find the total sales over the entire table:

```sql
SELECT item_id, sales, (SELECT SUM(sales) FROM yourTable) AS total
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY item_id;
```

Comment: Cool, this works if its a column, How can I do it if sales was an alias column?

Comment: ...that's not what your question asked.

Comment: Yep, just asking for a bit more out of curiosity.

Comment: Just subquery and apply my select.

Comment: you can't use an alias directly only with a cte or a subquery, that has that column name can be done